# Why smartd can't find my nvme device

Tags: nvme, smartmontools

```
greentea smartd[1147]: Configuration file /etc/smartd.conf was parsed, found DEVICESCAN, scanning devices
greentea smartd[1147]: Problem creating device name scan list
greentea smartd[1147]: In the system's table of devices NO devices found to scan
greentea smartd[1147]: Unable to monitor any SMART enabled devices. Try debug (-d) option. Exiting...
```

My `smartd.conf` has no change and has this line:

```
DEVICESCAN
```

I had changed the `DEVICESCAN` to `/dev/nvme0n1` still got the same error.

I tested on Debian 9.

Comment: Could be that your smartmontools are very old. You've not specified your distro and its version, so it's hard to say.

Comment: Tested by Debian 9.

Comment: Debian 9 is *extremely terribly outdated*. Install smartmontools 7.3 however you want.

Comment: It contains smartmontools 6.5 which were released five years ago. BTW the kernel in Debian 9 is also terribly dated, so you might have certain issues with your NVMe. Lastly Debian 9 EOL'ed almost a month ago. It means you're running a distro with known security vulnerabilities.